How to set method for instance dynamically in Python?
I need to update method for instance in runtime and my hypothetical code is looking like:
def set_method(where_to_set: str):
  def the_method(self):
    print(where_to_set, '->', self)
  return the_method


class A:
  one = set_method('as class attr `one`')
  two = None

  def __init__(self, necessary_variable):
    self.two = set_method(f'as instance overriden attr `two` with {necessary_variable}')
    self.three = set_method(f'as instance attr `three` with {necessary_variable}')

a = A('I`m important')

try:
  a.one()
except TypeError as e:
  print('one ->', e)
try:
  a.two()
except TypeError as e:
  print('two ->', e)
try:
  a.three()
except TypeError as e:
  print('three ->', e)

And output will be:
as class attr `one` -> <__main__.A object at 0x7f0a1638e250>
two -> set_method.<locals>.the_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
three -> set_method.<locals>.the_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Here is method one works as expected, but two and three raise TypeError.
However a necessary_variable is passed inside class instantiation so I can't set my method outside of __init__ or before constructor will be called.
So the question is, how to set set_method for an instance inside __init__ constructor and why this situation is happens at all? All these methods are attached to instance. Why self is not found?
PS in real life set_method is a part of external library, so it can not be changed.

You're trying to set methods dynamically inside the init method of your class, but you're not properly binding them to the instance. When you define a method in a class, it automatically becomes an instance method, which means the first argument is self, referring to the instance. However, when you dynamically assign a method inside init, it doesn't get automatically bound to the instance.

"PS in real life set_method is a part of external library, so it can not be changed." - it sounds like the "real" set_method isn't actually designed to be used like this, then. Why are you trying to use it like this? What is the real set_method?

You can just add a method to a class like that (type(self).two = ...), but not to an instance. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods

@user2357112 Here is a real set_method. It is supposed to be used as a wait_time attribute of User class, but I have to pass wait_time parameter that locust only parse after User instantiating (I want to change it via command line argument)
